# Building a multilevel hierarchy tree that is dynamic and not symmetric

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, hierarchy

I do not even know where to start with this. I can build a telerik tree that has parents and children, but I cannot figure out how to make it where it is not always symmetric. This is a validation tree so it tells the user error messages. For example, it should look like this:

```
Object ID (Main Property)
- Must start with a number (Description)
Employee Name (Main Property)
   Employee 1 (SubProperty)
       - Cannot be blank (Description)
   Employee 2 (Subproperty)
       - Cannot be blank (Description)
```

Any help with this or something that would lead me in the right direction would be helpful. This is my first time working with trees in WPF/C# so please be kind haha.

Edit: because I agree this is very vague:
Attached are images of my code. Since I am going through a virtual machine I had to do screen shots.

ViewModelBase:
[image]

ViewModel Cont:
[image]

XAML:

[image]

ValidationInfo:
[image]

Invalid Property:
[image]

If there is any other specific code you need to see, please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more details about your question, otherwise I wouldn't be surprised if it is closed. i.e., you've tagged it as `Telerik` why? Are you binding to a specific control? Or?

Comment: I am using a telerik radtreeview control. Sorry for being so vague.

Comment: Please post code as text and not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a vague question, but a class definition like;

```
class ValidationNode
{
    bool IsValid { get; }
    object EntityToValidatate { get; set; }
    string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    ValidationNode Parent { get; set; } 

    IList<ValidationNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Sounds like what you want to start with? Each node can have N child nodes, with some sort of attached validation logic at each step.

No doubt this is not going to completely answer your question, suggest you add more info there.